# WebView won't scroll for certain web page

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm trying to load **[Time.com](http://www.time.com/)** on my WebView.

Loading itself works fine, but the loaded page is not scrollable.

1. It works well with built-in browser, chrome browser
2. If I use other url(ex. http://www.google.com/), it works fine.

I think the problem is in the web page(html), but I can't figure out what's the problem.

Below is the code, though there's nothing special.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.yooiistudios.webviewperformance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.time.com/");
    }

    private class NewsWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that HTML5WebView works for my case.

Also I had a problem that for some video in webpage won't play on default android webview, and HTML5WebView also solved that problem.

Source code it self is a bit dirty and cluttered, it works fine.

Anyway, I leave a link here. Hope this helps someone who has same problem.

link: https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/trunk/HTML5WebView/src/org/itri/html5webview/HTML5WebView.java